# Joining a standalone VoxImplant conference

Tags: voximplant

I have a simple VoxImplant scenario which creates a standalone conference and calls its participants:

```js
require(Modules.Conference);

VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.Started, () => {
  let conf = VoxEngine.createConference();
  let { users } = JSON.parse(VoxEngine.customData());
  users.forEach((username) => {
    let call = VoxEngine.callUser({username: username, callerid: "root", displayName: "Whatever" });
    call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Connected, (e) => { VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(conf, e.call); });
  });
});
```

I use [StartScenarios endpoint](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/scenarios#startscenarios) to initiate the conference.

The calls arrive, users can answer them and hear each other. But what if they decline and decide to join later? I can see `callConference` methods in SDKs but they require `conferenceId`, how can I get it? `Conference` object doesn't seem to have `id` property, neither do `ConferenceParameters`.

VoxImplant conference sample has `create_conference` endpoint which inserts a record into a database and returns primary key but [it seems to be unused](https://github.com/voximplant/conference/search?q=create_conference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use [StartConference](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/scenarios#startconference) endpoint instead of StartScenario, it has `conference_name` parameter. Generate and pass conference name there, and pass the same name to `callConference` in order to join a running conference.